# Drillthrough function in Power BI column chart - show day numbers instead of dates

Tags: charts, hierarchy, powerbi, dax, drillthrough

I have created 2 different column charts in my Power BI report. The charts show the report usage by month and day (Day 1-31) - in this case for October. Only one month can be selected at a time.

I have added a drill-through function to the chart so the user can access a more detailed report. This works fine with the first chart when the Date field is placed under Axis (example: 2017-11-14).

When I instead try to use the Year, Month, Day fields under Axis only the day is being sent through to the drill-through report. For example November 6'th 2017 is being picked up at 6'th of each month. It seems that the drill-though function is only using the lowest level of data.

[image]

The first option works fine, however I would like it to look the the chart below where you see the number of each day instead of the entire date.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

**Edit:**

This is what the drillthrough filters look like on the drillthrough report page (I have selected November 9'th on the other page):

[image]

(År = Year, Månad = Month, Dag = Day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the issue:

I selected the drill down arrow on the right (in the top-left corner of the visualization) to drill down to the lowest level and **not** the arrow in the middle which I thought did the exact same thing except with more steps.

Now the drillthrough function works and all the values are passed to the next report!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your second option to work, you need to add Year/Month/Day values to Axis, then on drill-through report page also make sure you add these 3 fields to Drillthrough filters.

But if you only need to show shorter version of days instead of whole date, take a look at the formatting options ==> X-Axis, there you can turn off `Concatenate labels` and `grindlines` to get a nicer looking graph like in a picture below.

[image]

Main graph:

[image]

Drillthrough report:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this gives me the same result as before. I add year, month and day to the axis and the same for the drillthrough filters on the drillthrough report. When I use the function on a date the only value that goes through the drillthrough filter is the day number (example 15 if I choose the 15'th of November). The other filters are still on "All" and I receive the 15'th of each month instead of 15'th of November.

Comment: hm, without knowing more about your model its hard to tell.. are you using date table? I have tested this solution on my model and it it working as expected (see edited answer).